# how to generate feeds asynchronously using a background job in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process

The learn web development with rails tutorials by Michael Hartl mentions something like, "feed should be generated asynchronously using a background job." Is there any tutorial, book or screencast that explains how to go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

[railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) is a good place to start... my favourite way of dealing with such tasks is [daemons](http://railscasts.com/episodes/129-custom-daemon) but of course there are other options, look through the background jobs category on that site

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer please click accept button or let us know if you require more info please :)

Comment: say my site a user that following like 5000 other users, how to generate feed for that user.

Comment: If what you need is to just display new posts from those 5000 users on a web page you don't really need a background job. This is just a matter of fetching new posts from the database and forwarding results to a view. [Chapter 11 of Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top) goes over the details of implementing 'following users' feature.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) for background processing
You could find a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq) episode explaining how it works